# Tournament Graphs

Tags: combinatorics

Given a partially ordered set (i.e. poset) $P$, let $PC(P)$ be the smallest number of

chains that cover all the elements of $P$ . Let $PC'(P)$ be

the smallest number of pairwise disjoint chains that cover all the elements of $P$ (in other words,

we now want to decompose $P$ into chains, not only cover it). We clearly have $PC(P) ≤ PC'(P)$

Prove or disprove: for every $P$ we have $PC(P) = PC'(P)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $deg_{\mathrm{in}}v$, inward degree at $v$, to be the number of edges ending at $v$.

Then there exists a vertex $v_1$ that has smallest inward degree.

In this case, $deg_{\mathrm{in}}v_1 \leq \frac{2^{k}-1}{2} $.

Now, collect the vertices which there exists an edge from them to$v_1$.

This set has at most $\left\lfloor \frac{2^k-1}{2}\right\rfloor=2^{k-1}-1$ vertices.

In the subtournament of this vertices, choose $v_2$ that has smallest inward degree, and repeat this process, which ends within $k$ times.

Then the vertices $v_1,v_2,\cdots$ is the set of at most $k$ vertices that is not dominated.

For the additional question, refer to [this](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1963-08.pdf), the original Erdos' paper.